# Django REST Framework : "This field is required." with required=False and unique_together

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, unique

I want to save a simple model with Django REST Framework. The only requirement is that `UserVote.created_by` is set automatically within the `perform_create()` method. This fails with this exception:

```
{
    "created_by": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I guess it is because of the unique_together index.

models.py:

```
class UserVote(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='uservotes')
    rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('created_by', 'rating')
```

serializers.py

```
class UserVoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserVote
        fields = ('id', 'rating', 'created_by')
```

views.py

```
class UserVoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserVote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserVoteSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsCreatedByOrReadOnly, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

How can I save my model in DRF without having the user to supply `created_by` and instead set this field automatically in code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by explicitly creating and passing a new instance to the serializer. In the `UserVoteViewSet` you have to substitute `perform_create` with `create`:

```
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    uv = UserVote(created_by=self.request.user)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(uv, data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: That is neat! Works like a charm! Thanks so much for the hint!

Answer (score 8):

I was able to solve this with one-liner in `views.py`

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    request.data.update({'created_by': request.user.id})
    return super(UserVoteViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Since this view expects user to be authenticated, don't forget to extend `permission_classes` for `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: I'm getting `This QueryDict instance is immutable` error

Comment: @temirbek According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.copy) you can use `QueryDict.copy()`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The other weird way you can do is use signals like this

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=UserVote)
def intercept_UserVote(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    import inspect
    for frame_record in inspect.stack():
        if frame_record[3]=='get_response':
            request = frame_record[0].f_locals['request']
            break
    else:
        request = None

    instance.pre_save(request)
```

Then basically you can define pre_save in your model

```
def pre_save(self, request):
    # do some other stuff
    # Although it shouldn't happen but handle the case if request is None
    self.created_by = request.user
```

The advantage of this system is  you can use same bit of code for every model. If you need to change anything just change in `pre_save()`. You can add more stuff as well

Comment: Inspecting the stack? This is super hacky. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `ViewSet`:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

And the following on the `Serializer`:

```
class Meta:
    extra_kwargs = {
        'user': {
            'required': False,
        },
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code worked for me.

Even I was facing same error after many experiments found something, so added all fields in `serializer.py` in class meta, as shown below -

```
class Emp_UniSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer ):
    class Meta:
        model = table
        fields = '__all__'  # To fetch For All Fields
        extra_kwargs = {'std_code': {'required': False},'uni_code': {'required': False},'last_name': {'required': False},'first_name': {'required': False}}
```

Here, we can update any field which are in `"extra_kwargs"`, it wont show error `["This field is required."]`