# Getting Bad Request on seemily valid Django Rest Framework Post request asking for FK in Serializer data

Tags: angular, post, django-rest-framework, deserialization, bad-request

I am creating a new `SearchNeighborhood` object and connecting it to a already create `SearchCity` object in a `POST` request.

I have the following models

```
class SearchCity(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SearchNeighborhood(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(SearchCity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

my relevant serializer is:

```
class SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SearchNeighborhood
        fields = ('pk', 'neighborhood')
```

my view and relevant method is:

```
class CityNeighborhoodsListCreate(APIView):
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        citypk = kwargs.get('citypk', None)
        city=get_object_or_404(SearchCity,pk=citypk)
        serialized = SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serialized.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            validatedData = serialized.validated_data
            neighborhood = validatedData.get('neighborhood')
            neighborhoodobject = SearchNeighborhood(neighborhood= neighborhood, city = city)
            neighborhoodobject.save()
            createdneighborhood = SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(neighborhoodobject)
            return Response({
                'neighborhood': createdneighborhood.data
            })
```

I am using Angular 4

my `AJAX` request is:

```
addneighborhood(){
     const payload = {
       neighborhood: this.addneighborhoodform.form.value.addneighborhoodinput
     };
     this.suitsettingsservice.addneighborhood(payload)
       .subscribe(
         (req: any)=>{
             this.selectedcityneighborhoods.push(req);
         });
```

the error I am getting is:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/suitsadmin/settings/neighborhoodbycity", ok: false, …}
error:city :  "This field is required."
```

It is saying the city object is required. but I am not asking for it in the serializer. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

edit: I attempted the fix recommended in this post: 
[Django REST Framework : "This field is required." with required=False and unique_together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661853/django-rest-framework-this-field-is-required-with-required-false-and-unique)

of passing the city object into the serializer

```
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        citypk = kwargs.get('citypk', None)
        city=get_object_or_404(SearchCity,pk=citypk)
        serialized = SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(city,data=request.data)
```

## city passsed into serializer above

but it didnt change anything

edit:

I attempted to set the serializers city field to read only. But that also didnt help

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question again

its in my AJAX

I include a neighborhood field in the json but not a city. to satisfy the serailizer I must populate this field

```
addneighborhood(){
     const payload = {
       city: this.selectedcityname,
       neighborhood: this.addneighborhoodform.form.value.addneighborhoodinput
     };
     this.suitsettingsservice.addneighborhood(payload)
       .subscribe(
         (req: any)=>{
             this.selectedcityneighborhoods.push(req);
         });
```

Comment: YESSSS thanks! I had the same problem with my api app - django serializer had a 'username' input and in react it was 'user-name'